# how to scale image by percentage by carrierwave

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, percentage

I want to generate images in 25%, 50%, 75% size from original image, but seems carrierwave's resize_to_fill/fit not support percentage. Anyone knows how to do like this?

Thanks.

Comment: why not just calculate the right number ? can't you use a little function or such to translate 50% to the width/length ?

Comment: not sure if i can use variable like: process: resize_to_fit => [image.width*0.5, image.height*0.5]. By the way every uploaded image's size is not the same.

Answer (score 5):

After some research, i found one solution:

```
  process :store_dimensions

  version :r_3x do
    process :resize_to_fit_by_percentage => 0.75
  end

  private

  def resize_to_fit_by_percentage(percentage)
    resize_to_fit model.width*percentage, nil
  end


  def store_dimensions
    if file && model
      model.width, model.height = ::MiniMagick::Image.open(file.file)[:dimensions]
    end
  end
```

Firstly get the dimension of the uploaded image, then define a custom resize method(here is resize_to_fi_by_percentage), and resize image in this method like the code does.